# Como fazer toda requisição ser direcionada para uma subpasta? (HTACCESS)

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

já tentei vários tutoriais e nenhum funcionou além do `index.php`.

Uso o `LOCALHOST` e pretendo que toda requisição, de qualquer tipo, exemplo:

```
localhost:8080/teste.php
localhost:8080/imagens/algo.jpg
localhost:8080/teste2.php?querystring=ok
```

Seja redirecionado para a pasta dentro da `WWW` assim:
`/wamp/www/PASTA/(os arquivos das URLs estão aqui)`.

Mas preciso que o redirecionamento se pudesse ser invisível, seria perfeito.

O que tentei e só redirecionou a `INDEX.PHP` da `PASTA`, mas os outros arquivos ficaram dando erro 404.:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} localhost [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pasta/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao stackoverflow.

Comment: Muito obrigado. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui está o que eu usei para redirecionar para um subdiretório. Isso acontece de forma invisível e ainda permite  pedidos que correspondam a um arquivo existente:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdir/index.php [L]
```